# Installing Docker in Ubuntu, from repo. Can't find a repo

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to follow the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository).
However, when I run the command `sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

I get the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'
```

Also, when running `apt-cache madison docker-ce`, nothing shows up in the terminal...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1. Update APT:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**2. Install these packages first:**

```
sudo apt-get install \
     ca-certificates \
     curl \
     gnupg \
     lsb-release
```

**3. Add GPG keys:**

```
 curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
```

**4. Then add Docker repository:**

```
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

**5. Update again:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**6. Install docker-ce, cli and containerd.io:**

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

must work - be sure to execute all commands as root or with sudo.

You can also use their script to automate everything:

```
 curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
 sudo ./get-docker.sh
```

Comment: Thanks... the only thing I hadn't tried was step 5. All the others were done as you show. In the end, before reading your answer, I managed to install via package. Not sure if I'll have problems in the future.

Comment: Manual installation is included in the script(https://get.docker.com/). You can see so much code there because this code supports all linux distibutions. Manual installation or automatic installation, same effect...

Glad I could help :)

Comment: Step 5:
Update again:
sudo apt-get update

Magic!

Comment: Not so much magic as a basic understanding of how `apt-get` works. `apt-get update` is how you tell it to fetch fresh indices for all the configured source repos. (It would perhaps be nice if it could notice that the files where you configure your sources are newer than your indices, but there are many other cases where it couldn't know whether you need an update until you actually fetch new indices anyway.)

Answer (score 5):

use `curl https://get.docker.com/ | bash -` this is an automated script that will work in most of the cases

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the end, before reading your answer, I installed via package. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @Krzysztof Raciniewski answer, to avoid permission denied error or if you come across one, use the following post installation code to

1. **create docker group**

`sudo groupadd docker` and

2. **add user to the group with**

`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

log out and log back in for docker membership to take effect or restart your VM if you use one.

Comment: This is unrelated to the actual installation of Docker, and should perhaps simply be deleted.

Comment: @tripleee It may not be relevant for you but for newbies installing docker for the first time, this is not an uncommon issue.

Comment: Indeed, it would probably be a useful answer on a different question.

Comment: The Docker installation package for Debian already creates the group (but adding your user to the group is useful). On many other architectures, this is not going to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Install `docker` is pretty straightforward:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Comment: Not anymore, in case anybody sees this answer: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-old-versions

Answer (score 0):

you can try thhis

```
sudo apt install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update -y
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```